# pybluez not detecting any devices

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluez, pybluez

I have the following Python code:

```
import bluetooth
print(bluetooth.discover_devices())
```

This always waits a few seconds and prints out an empty list.

My bluetooth adapter appears to be working, as I can discover devices with `bluetoothctl` easily by typing `scan on`.

How can I fix/troubleshoot this?

Comment: Although a bit late to answer, but were you running the python interpreter with sudo?

Comment: Again a bit late, but I have the same problem @DanielSantos.  Tried with sudo, still no luck.  Notable that I used `sudo idle`, so not exactly the python command.  Running python 3.6.7

Answer (score 1):

Try using: 
`print(bluetooth.discover_devices(duration=8, lookup_names=True, flush_cache=True, lookup_class=False))`
as [this](https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez/blob/master/examples/simple/inquiry.py) example sugests

Comment: This doesn't really change how the scan is performed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like PyBlueZ doesn't support BLE, but you could try using alternative libraries like [bluepy](https://pypi.org/project/bluepy/) or [pygatt](https://pypi.org/project/pygatt/).

I'm currently using bluepy. It's kinda hard to start with the documentation, but in the end, it works just fine.